# Camera Module 3, on Raspberry Pi 4, running Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: camera

Has anyone managed to get the Camera Module 3 working on Ubuntu / RPi 4?

I just bought the new camera to replace an older noir camera.

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS 

$ vcgencmd get_camera
supported=1 detected=0

$ uname -a
Linux 5.15.0-1024-raspi #26-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT

$ cat /boot/firmware/config.txt
start_x=1
```

However there are no `bcm2835-v4l2` entries when I plug the new camera in and reboot :(

What can I try to check for camera support?

---

The previously camera was detected under v4l and was accessible via ffmpeg etc.. at `/dev/video0`.

The previously camera showed up in dmesg like this:

```
[    1.605801] bcm2835-v4l2-0: scene mode selected 0, was 0
[   11.607833] bcm2835-v4l2-0: V4L2 device registered as video0 - stills mode > 1280x720
[   11.614931] bcm2835-v4l2-0: Broadcom 2835 MMAL video capture ver 0.0.2 loaded.
```

What can I do to get the Camera Module 3 running on Ubuntu / Raspberry Pi 4?

Thanks

Comment: Found a forum post after tweaking my google term: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=2073750#p2073750